# tabular data model in data store lake for power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

i have requirement to consume data from data lake store and display in power BI. data size is big it may be 20 GB or 50 GB, i don't know what size will come in feature.also i cannot use Azure DW and Azure Analysis service.

now i proposed a solution i should create a tabular file(pivot table) in azure data  lake store  with aggregated date with all table joins in   data like store

Geography Name Product-Name Salesyerar2015 Salesyerar2017 userId

i need to show two year of data in power BI report.

for month level i have 24 columns for measures. in power i use import data from data lake store.

if data size is more i suggest power BI Premium  for bigger data file so it should accommodate in cache( 50 GB limitations)

Now for small data set it is work fine, i cannot able to test big files.

now i want to know when i have date level tabular file is required how i accommodate in tabular model.

also i want to know this proposed design is correct or do we have any other approach to handle this use case.

Regards,
manish

Comment: Hi, Any body can Microsoft Suggest me, it is urgent to communicate Client.

Comment: Hi all, it's really hard to me understand what is best way to connect Power BI and data lake store. we cannot say size of  Data Lake Store= Size of PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look into the U-SQL sampling function available out of the box in the Azure Data Lake Analytics service to reduce your datasets to a size that can be consumed by Power BI. It's a technique we use a lot.

Example U-SQL:

```
@Output =
    SELECT
        *
    FROM 
        @ParsedJSON
    SAMPLE UNIFORM
        (0.04); //4%
```

Then output the files to data lake store for consumption.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot for replay. but we don't to use data lake analytic to increase cost. what is other options.